# Do Web browsers use different port numbers for open tabs?

Tags: multithreading, tabs, browser, port

I'm wondering how browsers internally works.
Now, connecting to different Web sites using 'Tabs' within the same browser can be handled in one of two ways:
1 - Using threads
2 - Using Different Source Port Numbers for each open tab

I know there might not be a single answer for this question, and it might differ from one browser to another, however all responses are appreciated.

Thanks

---

Thanks for everyone.I really appreciate that. 
My question relates to the Source Port at the client side. I'm asking if the browser uses different source ports for each tab it opens, or the same source port for the entire process 'I mean window that includes different tabs', or the same source port for the entire windows?

Or, do web browsers use threads?

Comment: Threads wouldn't be much help with the asynchronous nature of HTTP connections...

Answer (score 20):

Threads and ports are separate and mostly unrelated concepts.

Threads are what the local computer processor does to handle computations, such as drawing to the screen or waiting for Internet traffic. There's probably a separate thread (and more) for those operations in each tab.

Ports are what the traffic itself is identified by (in TCP and UDP). In order to communicate your browser would open a local port (usually something big like ~5000, and that doesn't matter as long as its unique) and connect to the server on usually port 80 (the one the server is listening on). If your computer didn't know the remote port it couldn't connect, but its standard to use 80 for HTTP, for example.

Browsers open tabs in separate threads (and new ones even in separate processes for security and reliability reasons), and use separate ports on the client side. So yes, the answer is both threads and ports. They always use the same remote port unless you physically specify otherwise (for example, connecting to a website using https:// instead of http:// uses a separate port because that's how that protocol was made). You can specify a port to use in modern browsers with :# after the name, too. (example: http://www.google.com:81/, however that will fail because that's not what port they listen on!)

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot for this explanation

Answer (score 10):

A quick check using `netstat` (or `sockstat` on BSD machines) reveals that different source port numbers are used for different connections. In that regard, you are right.

Firefox uses at least one thread for each tab. Each thread could open multiple connections for different data (for example, loading images from a media server and content from the web server). Each connection should have its own source port.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser it uses different threads or different processes for each tab. The local ports used probably don't have much to do with different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from Cisco CCNA course:

For instance, assume a host is initiating a web page request from a web server. When the host initiates the web page request, the source port number is dynamically generated by the host to uniquely identify the conversation. Each request generated by a host will use a different dynamically created source port number. This process allows multiple conversations to occur simultaneously.

In the request, the destination port number is what identifies the type of service being requested of the destination web server.. For example, when a client specifies port 80 in the destination port, the server that receives the message knows that web services are being requested.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

no! it usually uses port 80 by default unless specified. for example www.someweb.com:8080.

Tabs within browser i am assuming ran on different threads

Comment: The different port numbers mentioned in the question refer to the _client-side_ port, these are unrelated to the server port which as you said is port 80 in most cases.